# Empty record MySQL, how find?

Tags: mysql

Please help to fix this error:

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE p.user_id, p.project_id, p.cid, p.project_title, p.additional_info, p.buynow_price, p.date_added, p.highlite, p.project_details, p.views, p.bids, p.currentprice, p.currencyid, p.buynow, p.filtered_auctiontype, p.buynow_purchases, p.date_starts, p.buynow_qty_lot, p.items_in_lot, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.date_end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-08-05 18:14:50') AS mytime, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.date_starts) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-08-05 18:14:50') AS starttime, p.donation, p.filter_budget, p.reserve, p.project_state, p.bid_details, p.filter_escrow, p.filter_gateway, p.charityid, p.jobs_price
          FROM xxx_projects AS p
          LEFT JOIN xxx_users u ON(p.user_id = u.user_id)
          WHERE p.visible = '1'
          AND p.status = 'open'
          AND p.project_state = 'product'
          AND u.status = 'active'
          AND p.project_id IN (88414723, 5043541, 98506492, 36121136, 84626697, , 4408122, 49183201, 56318356, 89533629, 16433073, 70069844, 6242686, 8745727, 10816822, 8745727, 27902749, 41807041, 61556755, 46837725, 38855144, 69491982, 27240408, 20425411)
```

> MySQL Error  : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ' 4408122, 49183201, 56318356, 89533629, 16433073,
>   70069844, 6242686, 8745727, 10' at line 8

I think in db is empty record but i can'f find it...

Comment: `84626697, , 4408122` is not valid.

Comment: i now, but i don't now how fix it

Comment: Well you seem to be generating the SQL somewhere, so you need to provide that code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a double comma in `84626697, , 4408122`. Just remove one comma (i.e., make it `84626697, 4408122`) and you should be good to go.

Comment: all data ilance get from db, i think in db is empty record, can you tell how query send to find it

Comment: i tried: SELECT SQL_CACHE p.project_id

FROM xxx_projects AS p

WHERE p.project_id IS NULL OR p.project_id = ' ' but not work

Comment: @veramix project_id doesn't appear to be a string.  So it can be either a number like in `IN` clause of SQL in your question or if `null` is allowed it can be `null` too.  but it will not be and empty string.  In your SQL `IN` clause,  instead of `xxxx,  , xxxx`  try `xxxx,null,xxxx`